# cvCreateVideoWriter (OpenCV 2.2 + FFMPEG)

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm working with OpenCV 2.2 for Android under Windows, and faced a problem when using cvCreateVideoWriter. It always returns NULL. I'm guessing it has something to do with library FFMPEG not being properly built. The thing is that I followed instructions in http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.2, and since FFMPEG is included as a 3rd party library (at least I can see the source withing the whole OpenCV package) I thought I didn't have to do anything extra to get this library installed. I might be wrong. How do I check if the library was correctly built (or built at all)? Do I need to make any changes to the default make files?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: And also, assuming it's well compiled, which are the headers (.h) I need to #include? avcodec.h? avformat.h? any other?

Comment: How are you calling `cvCreateVideoWriter()`? Can't help you without source code.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 important things to consider when using `cvCreateVideoWriter()`:

- Your application needs rights to create files and be able to write on them. Make sure you have setup the necessary directory permissions for it to do so.
- The 2nd argument of the function is the code of codec used to compress the frames. For For instance, `CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1')` is MPEG-1 codec and `CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')` defines motion-jpeg.

A typical call may look like this:

```
CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("video.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), fps, size, 0);
if (!write)
{
   // handle error
}
```

I suggest calling cvCreateVideoWriter with different codecs. It may be that your platform doesn't support the one you are using right now.

I don't know if the default build for Android enables the flag `HAVE_FFMPEG`, but you need to have ffmpeg installed and it's best to make sure this flag is enable when compiling OpenCV.